# Call another HTTp request inside after an HTML request in an angular service

Tags: angular, rxjs, pipe, subscribe, switchmap

In some angular service, I need to call a PUT method named, I need to call another GET method once after it is completed. Then the results from GET method should be stored in a variable in the service itself.

The code which I have written has some issue with it. Because when I call the service from the component, isUpdateSuccess shown as undefined in the component.

Here, I do not need to pass the ‘application’ object to the component. I need to pass only the ApplicationStatusModel as an observable. But I need to save application object to a variable named myApplication as I mentioned above.

I read few articles and went through some Stackoverflow posts too. No luck yet.

**Service**

```
private myApplication: ApplicationHeader;

updateStudentAssessmentStatus(model: ApplicationStatusModel): Observable<boolean> {

const data = this.svcHttp.put<boolean>(`${this.routePrefix}/${model.studentID}/applicationAssessmentStatus`, model)
  .pipe(
    switchMap(() => this.getApplicationHeaderById(model.studentID)
      .pipe(map(application => {
        console.log(`Application from update status ${JSON.stringify(application)}`);
        this.myApplication = application;
      })))
  );
return data;
```

}

**component (which calls 'updateStudentAssessmentStatus')**

```
this.svcApplication.updateStudentAssessmentStatus(statusModel).subscribe((isUpdateSuccess: boolean) => {
      //isUpdateSuccess is NULL here.
      if (!isUpdateSuccess) {

      } else {

      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

`map()` is used to transform an event into something else. You're currently using it to transform an ApplicationHeader into `undefined`, since you don't return anything from the map callback.

To apply a side-effect, `tap()` is what you need.

And you don't need so much nesting either.

```
private myApplication: ApplicationHeader;

updateStudentAssessmentStatus(model: ApplicationStatusModel): Observable<ApplicationHeader> {

  return this.svcHttp.put<boolean>(`${this.routePrefix}/${model.studentID}/applicationAssessmentStatus`, model).pipe(
    switchMap(() => this.getApplicationHeaderById(model.studentID)),
    tap(application => {
      console.log(`Application from update status ${JSON.stringify(application)}`);
      this.myApplication = application;
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and code. I am getting an error after applying it. However, I am trying to get rid of those errors myself. I will comment the errors below just for your information. :-)

Comment: ERROR in src/app/main/services/application.service.ts(1310,5): error TS2322: Type 'Observable<boolean | ApplicationHeader>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<boolean>'.
  Type 'boolean | ApplicationHeader' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
    Type 'ApplicationHeader' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
src/app/main/services/application.service.ts(1314,9): error TS2322: Type 'boolean | ApplicationHeader' is not assignable to type 'ApplicationHeader'.
  Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'ApplicationHeader'.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. The reurn type of updateStudentAssessmentStatus should be Observable<ApplicationHeader>, not Observable<boolean>. And you know that the update and the following get are successful because there is no error being emitted by the returned observable. Not because it emits a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .pipe() upon your first http subscription.

```
return your-First-Http-Request().pipe(tap((res: your response) => {

        your-First-Http-Request()
    }
})
```